# Vertical content align in Android EditText

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, android-xml, layout-gravity

I have a multi-line `EditText`:

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:width="250dip"
    android:text=""
    android:maxLength="760"
    android:lines="4">
</EditText>
```

Now the content is aligned to the middle. And I'd like to have the content aligned to the top.

Is there a property to do that?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Try this:
`android:gravity="top"`

```
<EditText 
   android:layout_gravity="center"  
   android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_below="@+id/lblMessage"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:width="250dip"
   android:text="hello" 
   android:maxLength="760"
   android:gravity="top"                       
   android:lines="4"/>
```

so `android:gravity="top"` sets the text at the "Top" Position.

**You can also set different `android:gravity` attribute value such as `center`, `bottom`, `center_vertical`, `left`, `right`, `center_horizontal`, etc.**

Enjoy !!

Comment: How to set it programmatically?

Comment: To set programmatically, call your EditText and use gravity property on that. It should work.. Something like: EditText eText=(EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.something); eText.setGravity(); It will work ..Freewind

Answer (score 18):

Try

```
android:gravity="top"
```